# Removing single pixel space around input slider

Tags: html, css

Can someone help me figure out why there's a single pixel space between the border of the input range and the top and right edge of the thumb slider? I don't recall this being here before and I can't figure out what is causing it.

```css
@media screen and (min-width:720px) {
  .financecalc {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    width: 300px;
  }
  .financetext {
    width: calc(100% - 330px);
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:960px) {
  .financecalc {
    width: 400px;
  }
  .financetext {
    width: calc(100% - 430px);
  }
}

.paycalc {
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid #b2221b;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 5px 1px black;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: calc(100% - 24px);
}

.paycalc label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.paycalc input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  border: 2px solid #b2221b;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: block;
  height: 16px;
  opacity: 0.9;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: calc(100% - 4px);
}

.paycalc input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 16px;
  background: #b2221b;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.paycalc input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 20px;
  height: 16px;
  background: #b2221b;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.calcSlider {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
}

#interestSlider {
  direction: rtl;
}

.calcBox,
.interestBox,
.paymentBox {
  background-color: #555;
  border: 3px inset #909090;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: white;
  padding: 6px;
}

.calcBox {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  width: 62px;
}

.interestBox {
  width: 100%;
}

.paymentBox {
  width: calc(100% - 18px);
}

.calcBox div,
.paymentBox div {
  color: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.calcBox div:first-of-type,
.paymentBox div:first-of-type {
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 12px;
}

.calcBox div:last-of-type,
.paymentBox div:last-of-type {
  font-size: 18px;
  width: calc(100% - 14px);
}
```

```html
<div id="calculator" class="financecalc">
  <form id="myForm" class="paycalc">
    <div class="calcSlider">
      <label for="downPaymentSlider">Down Payment</label>
      <input id="downPaymentSlider" name="downPaymentSlider" type="range" value="500" min="250" max="5000" step="50">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

[image: spacing example]

Comment: Looks OK on Chrome Win 11 ..

Comment: Please move/copy the code to this question.

Comment: SO has a snippet tool where you can place your fiddle. Using 3rd party IDEs are not a good idea because eventually, they can be deleted or changed.

Comment: Do you find the white bit comes and goes with zooming? I can see it on Windows10 Edge/Chrome but it varies with zoom. It's screen pixels (not a whole CSS pixel) 'left behind' when the system tries to map between CSS pixels and screen pixels (there are several screen pixels per CSS pixel on modern displays). It's a bit like a rounding error.

Comment: Not sure if this will help at all but I can only recreate it for certain levels of zoom.

Comment: Yeah, it seems to change with Zoom. At 100% I see the white, but at different levels of zoom it's present or absent. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Same here... When I zoom to 175%, I get the result you have. But there's not really a reason to zoom in.

Answer (score 0):

The white line can appear at various zoom levels depending on how the system is mapping CSS pixels to screen pixels (there being several screen pixels to a CSS pixel on many higher def screens nowadays).

It's a bit like a rounding error, a screen pixel can get 'left behind' in the calculations.

As your thumb and your border are the same color here's a slightly unpleasant hack, but it overcomes the problem visually.

This snippet makes the height of the thumb equal to the height of the input element plus its top and bottom borders - this gives the system lots of wiggle room when it's dropping or including a screen pixel and the user won't see bits of white.

```css
@media screen and (min-width:720px) {
  .financecalc {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    width: 300px;
  }
  .financetext {
    width: calc(100% - 330px);
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:960px) {
  .financecalc {
    width: 400px;
  }
  .financetext {
    width: calc(100% - 430px);
  }
}

.paycalc {
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid #b2221b;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 5px 1px black;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: calc(100% - 24px);
}

.paycalc label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.paycalc input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  border: 2px solid #b2221b;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: block;
  height: 16px;
  opacity: 0.9;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: calc(100% - 4px);
}

.paycalc input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 16px;
  height: 20px;
  /* 16px + 2x2px */
  background: #b2221b;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.paycalc input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #b2221b;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.calcSlider {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
}

#interestSlider {
  direction: rtl;
}

.calcBox,
.interestBox,
.paymentBox {
  background-color: #555;
  border: 3px inset #909090;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: white;
  padding: 6px;
}

.calcBox {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  width: 62px;
}

.interestBox {
  width: 100%;
}

.paymentBox {
  width: calc(100% - 18px);
}

.calcBox div,
.paymentBox div {
  color: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.calcBox div:first-of-type,
.paymentBox div:first-of-type {
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 12px;
}

.calcBox div:last-of-type,
.paymentBox div:last-of-type {
  font-size: 18px;
  width: calc(100% - 14px);
}
```

```html
<div id="calculator" class="financecalc">
  <form id="myForm" class="paycalc">
    <div class="calcSlider">
      <label for="downPaymentSlider">Down Payment</label>
      <input id="downPaymentSlider" name="downPaymentSlider" type="range" value="500" min="250" max="5000" step="50">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Whoops! I forgot about the left/right potential gap. But will leave this answer here in the hopes someone will think of a further hack for those gaps.